# how to accept oracle terms for java download in chef

Tags: java, chef-infra

I am using ark to download jdk7u51 from oracle downloads.

```
ark 'jdk' do
  url  'http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz'
  path "/home/myapp/apps/jdku51" 
  owner 'myapp'
  group 'myapp'
  action :put
 end
```

However, this does not download the actual file, as the license agreement is not accepted.

Since I'm using vagrant, i added the following in .kitchen.yml . But that did not help.

```
suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[java]
    attributes:
      java:
        jdk_version: 7
        oracle:
          accept_oracle_download_terms: true
          jce:
            enabled: true
```

What is the best way to get the oracle license terms accepted?

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to use OpenJDK?

Comment: I dont know what ark is however I have had to download the JDK using wget and theres a cookie you have to add to download it. I belive its `Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie`

Comment: @chrylis: main reason is that i want to install it in a separate location in /home/newuser/java for local testing. I don't know how to force rpms to install locally i.e. in user home location

Comment: @user1587001 did you had a look at the [java cookbook](https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java) before trying to reinvent the wheel (it uses a modified version of the ark provider under the hood) ?

Comment: @Tensibai, yes i did actually. I tried setting the path. It does not work for the jre. for the jce it installs at the custom location.

Comment: @user1587001 what are you talking about here ? jce is part of the jdk as the jre is, if you have a simple jre it's probabaly not installed by the cookbook at all.

Comment: @Tensibai: My big reason for using custom script oracle jdk was so that i can use tar.gz  and extract to a custom location. to my knowledge its not possible with openjdk rpm/deb . as for  the java cookbook, it installs the jdk in its default location /usr/lib/java, if I am not wrong.and i could not find a way to change that. i was able to change the jce install location only

Answer (score 3):

Found an answer. This works for me.

```
remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz" do
  source "http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz"
      headers({"Cookie" => "oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"})
end
```